# Can't connect to RAID subsystem on IBM BladeCenter SAS RAID controller module to perform firmware update

Tags: raid, sas, firmware, bladecenter

I've come across and old IBM BladeCenter S and I'm having issues with the SAS/RAID system:

Is possible to update the firmware for an IBM SAS RAID Controller Module (from R1.07 to 1.3.1.010) without having to telnet into the RAID subsystem, as per IBM's instructions?

I can both use the web interface and telnet into the SAS switch subsystem. But I can't connect to the RAID controller subsystem; all I get is:

```
telnet: connect to address 192.168.70.139: Network is unreachable
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I did succeed once, but the connection was dropped whenever I tried to run a command. I have yet to replicate it since, and I don't know which module (one definitely has issues).

I have restored everything to factory defaults (AMM, I/O modules, blades) and updated the firmware of everything else, but still no luck.

There's an option to update the firmware in the module's web interface, but I have yet to come across a download on IBM's site for this file, or find it among the files that the firmware update script creates (*ibm_fw_bcsw_s0cl-1.3.1.010_linux_noarch.sh*).

I know that one of the two modules has issues (according to the previous owner) and it will not perform a firmware rollback via telnet (see code B). 
Whereas the other has no complaints. I have tried disconnecting both from the system in case either was interfering with the other module.

**Code A, version info:**

```
MAIN> raid
ITEM               STATUS
-------------------------
RAID Status        GOOD
RAID Post Result   Done

MAIN> version

Maxim Semiconductor VSC7157

Chip Version      : 03
Card Revision     : 07
CPLD Revision     : 0A
Firmware Build ID : S0SW01D   
Firmware Revision : R1.07
CPU Version       : 0000AC13

MAIN>
```

**Code B, bad module:**

```
MAIN> fwrollback

Validating the firmware image in back up space. Please wait a moment- 
OK.
   Sense Connection closed by foreign host.
XXX:~ XXX$ telnet -l USERID 192.168.70.129
Trying 192.168.70.129...
Connected to 192.168.70.129.
Escape character is '^]'.
=== IBM BladeCenter(R) SAS RAID Controller Module ===

Login: USERID
Password: ********
USERID logged on


MAIN> CPLDDRV: **ERROR** Reading IP Configuration has failed! No change was made.
CPLDDRV: **ERROR** Reading IP Configuration has failed! No change was made.
CPLDDRV: **ERROR** Reading IP Configuration has failed! No change was made.
...
```